# $elemMatch support (or alternative)

Tags: casl

I need to do an find operation on an array of objects in order to determine the permission, basically define a permission based on on whether an object exist in an array of objects defined as an attribute on the subject.

In MongoDB I would have used $elemMatch, is it supported? or do you recommend an alternative?

**Example:**

```
department = {
     name: "name",
     employees : [
      {
       Name: "John Doe",
       title: "assistant"
      },
      {
       Name: "Jane Doe",
       title: "Manager"
      }
     ]
};
```

I need to define an ability to only allow someone with the name "Jane Doe" and title "Manager" to update the name of the department.

Please do not focus on the very awful data model here, its just an example of what I am trying to achieve. The main focus is basing an ability on the existing of an object within a field that is an array of objects.

Fantastic library btw!

Comment: Could you please mark question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

`$elemMatch` is supported. You can use it.